# jQuery - GET parameters undefined on $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm currently working on a mobile application based on jQuery mobile, and I'm facing a problem passing data between two pages. I use a simple link to navigate to my next page.

Here is the code I use to create a div that is supposed to navigate to the ViewGame.html page when clicked :

```
var currentDiv = "<a href=\"ViewGame.html?id=" + item.id + "\"><div class=\"roomContainer\" >";
            currentDiv += "<div class=\"roomContainerTitle\">"+ item.name +"</div>";
            currentDiv += "<div>"+ item.nickname +"</div>";
            currentDiv += "<div>"+ item.game +"</div>";
            currentDiv += "<div>"+ item.rank +"</div>";
            currentDiv += "<div>"+ item.language +"</div>";
            currentDiv += "</div></a>";
            //alert(currentDiv);
            $("#resultRooms").append(currentDiv);
```

As you can see, I need to transfert an id from the current page to ViewGame, so I decided to put it as a GET parameter.

The problem is that in the js script attached to ViewGame.html, the parameter is undefined at the beginning. Here is some code so you can understand :

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<script src="js/viewGameScript.js"></script>

<div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <p id="headerTitle">ViewGame</p>
</div>

<div data-role="content" id="mainContent">
    <button id="viewGameButton">Refresh</button>

    <div id="viewGameRoomTitle"></div>
    <div>
        <span class="profileSubTitle">Game : </span>
        <span id="viewGameRoomGame"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="profileSubTitle">Rank : </span>
        <span id="viewGameRoomRank"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="profileSubTitle">Author : </span>
        <span id="viewGameRoomAuthor"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="profileSubTitle">Language : </span>
        <span id="viewGameRoomLanguage"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="profileSubTitle">Free slots : </span>
        <span id="viewGameRoomNbSlots"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="profileSubTitle">Start time : </span>
        <span id="viewGameRoomTimeStart"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

var displayRoom = function() {
    var id = getUrlParameter('id');
    //alert(window.location.href + "  ---   " + id);

    $.get('http://192.168.1.42/m8_server/room.php?id=' + id, function(data) {
        var room = $.parseJSON(data).room;

        $("#viewGameRoomTitle").html(room.name);
        $("#viewGameRoomAuthor").html(room.nickname);
        $("#viewGameRoomGame").html(room.game);
        $("#viewGameRoomRank").html(room.rank);
        $("#viewGameRoomLanguage").html(room.language);
        $("#viewGameRoomNbSlots").html(room.nbSlots);
        $("#viewGameRoomTimeStart").html(room.timeStart);
    });
};

$("#viewGameButton").on("click", function() {
    displayRoom();
});

displayRoom();
```

});

You can see code of ViewGame.html and viewGameScript.js.
The fact is that on the first call of displayRoom (at the end of the script), the id is undefined (the url is correct, but with no parameter), but when I click on my #viewGameButton, everything works perfectly. I think when the code is primary executed, the GET parameters are not set, but I have no idea why :/

I hope you guys can help me !

PS : sorry for english mistakes, I'm not a native english speaker

Comment: What's the difference between the first and the second call?

Comment: The first call is done when the script is loaded, and the second is done when I click on a button (so some seconds after, and the GET parameters seems to be set during this period...)

Comment: where is this resultRooms div placed?

Comment: It is placed is another page, called FindGame.html. This page is loaded dynamically using the load() method. We have a main page that contain a panel which we use as a burger menu, and when the user click on one of the items, a page is loaded and placed in a div of the main page. FindGame is one the those pages.

Comment: Moreover, ViewGame is an independant page that is not accessible from the burger menu.
PS : sorry for the repost, but I wasn't allowed to edit my previous comment

Comment: Need more details buddy.

Comment: What kind of details should I give to help you ?